# wpdb->query UPDATE query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
while ($count <= 18614) {
            $random_message = $message_array[mt_rand(0, count($message_array) - 1)];
            $cell_type_pre = $conn->get_results("SELECT `post_type` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `id` = " . $count);
            $cell_type = $cell_type_pre[0]->{"post_type"};
            if ($cell_type == "post") {
                $conn->query("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_excerpt` = '" . $random_message . "' WHERE `ID` = " . $count . " AND `post_excerpt` = NULL;");
            }
            if ($cell_type == "attachment") {
                $conn->query("UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = '" . $random_message . "' WHERE `ID` = " . $count . " AND `post_content` = NULL;");
            }
            $count++;
```

I'm trying to add a random message from $message_array to this WP table based on the post_type condition. Nothing happens.

Comment: `post_excerpt = NULL` does nothing , null cant be compared this way it should be `post_excerpt is null`

Comment: FYI it's a really bad idea to pass any variables verbatim into an SQL query. This is open to SQL injection.

Comment: I know. this script is for the site's admin on a private page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works using wpdb->update..

```
while ($count <= 18614) {
            $random_message = $message_array[mt_rand(0, count($message_array) - 1)];
            $cell_type_pre = $conn->get_results("SELECT `post_type` FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `id` = " . $count);
            $cell_type = $cell_type_pre[0]->{"post_type"};
            if ($cell_type == "post") {
                $conn->update('wp_posts', array('post_excerpt' => $random_message),array( 'ID' => $count, 'post_excerpt' => ''));
            }
            if ($cell_type == "attachment") {
                $conn->update('wp_posts', array('post_content' => $random_message),array( 'ID' => $count, 'post_content' => ''));
            }
            $count++;
        }
```